# Arrange images by css

Tags: html, css

---

[My demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faIMs.png)
These images appear by this order but I want to display them by this order (1-3-4-2)

I use the order like in my code but that does not work, how can I order them using `CSS` but **without** **flex** as it appears to put them in one row.
Also how can I make them **rotate around** `x & y` **not only** **z** to appear as **3d rotation**.

```css
ul {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
   
}
#1   {order: 1;}
#2  {order: 4;}
#3 {order: 2;}
#4  {order: 3;}

li {
  float: left;
   width: 100%
   
}
#new{
    width: 50%
}
img {
   opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
li:nth-child(1) > img {
     width: 20%;
    margin-left:40%;
}
li:nth-child(2) > img {
     width: 40%;
     margin-left:20%;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

li:nth-child(3) > img {
    width: 40%;
    margin-left:40%;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}

li:nth-child(4) > img {
  width: 20%;
       margin-left:40%;
  animation-delay: 9s;
}


@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
     transform:rotateZ(0deg);
   
  
  }
  
  100% {
       transform:rotateZ(360deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

      <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

      
  </head>

  <body>
      
<ul>
  <li><img id="1" src="https://i.imgur.com/6WD0tuL.png" /></li>
  <li id="new"><img id="2" src="https://i.imgur.com/6WD0tuL.png" /></li>
  <li id="new"><img id="3" src="https://i.imgur.com/6WD0tuL.png" /></li>
  <li><img id="4" src="https://i.imgur.com/6WD0tuL.png" /></li>
 
</ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is link of image https://imgur.com/a/8u2al

Comment: Here's a very nice 3D rotating earth.  http://sebastien.drouyer.com/jquery.earth-3d if might be a bit of an overkill for what you want, but I can't see how you can make a flat image into a 3D rotating earth.

Comment: Looking @ https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters identifiers cannot start with a digit.

Comment: wow nice it worked very well ... Thanks helb for your help

Comment: It's a nice 3D animation but will not help me , thanks  KIKO Software

Comment: Ok  Ron van der Heijden thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the timing of your animation-delays in your css to get the order you want. To get images to translate in 3D you can look at samples at [W3 3D Transforms](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_3dtransforms.asp); Although, if you actually want to make it look like the earth image is rotating in 3D, then you could use a sprite image/gif.

```css
ul {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
/*#1   {order: 1;}
#2  {order: 4;}
#3 {order: 2;}
#4  {order: 3;}*/

li {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
#new {
  width: 50%;
}
img {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
li:nth-child(1) > img {
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 40%;
}
li:nth-child(2) > img {
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

li:nth-child(3) > img {
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 40%;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

li:nth-child(4) > img {
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 40%;
  animation-delay: 9s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <ul>
    <li><img id="1" src="https://i.imgur.com/c117rlU.png" /></li>
    <li id="new"><img id="2" src="https://i.imgur.com/c117rlU.png" /></li>
    <li id="new"><img id="3" src="https://i.imgur.com/c117rlU.png" /></li>
    <li><img id="4" src="https://i.imgur.com/c117rlU.png" /></li>

  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before sharing any solutions, can I address some problems with how you are selecting elements in CSS?

- Duplicate `id` 'new'. An `id` is meant to uniquely identify an element; use `class` instead to target multiple elements.
- Mixing more than one way to select elements - `#id` and `nth-child`. You should pick just one, which will make your code easier to read.

Now on to a choice of solutions...

## A) Quick fix

Just change the `animation-delay` values:

```
li:nth-child(2) > img {
  ...
  animation-delay: 9s;
}

li:nth-child(3) > img {
  ...
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

li:nth-child(4) > img {
  ...
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
```

Done.

## B) CSS Grid

Instead of changing the animation-delays, you tried to reorder elements themselves. This is how you do it with CSS Grid. Most newer browsers support this; [check if it matters to you](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid).

```css
#globes {
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "... g-1 ..."
    "g-3 ... g-4"
    "... g-2 ..."
  ;
}

#globe-1 { grid-area: g-1; }
#globe-2 { grid-area: g-2; }
#globe-3 { grid-area: g-3; }
#globe-4 { grid-area: g-4; }

#globe-1 > img { animation-delay: 0; }
#globe-2 > img { animation-delay: 3s; }
#globe-3 > img { animation-delay: 6s; }
#globe-4 > img { animation-delay: 9s; }

#globes img {
  width: 40%;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotateZ(0);
  } 
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="globes">
  <div id="globe-1"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/6WD0tuL.png"></div>
  <div id="globe-2"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/6WD0tuL.png"></div>
  <div id="globe-3"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/6WD0tuL.png"></div>
  <div id="globe-4"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/6WD0tuL.png"></div>
</div>
```

## C) Flexbox

I want to add this because... who said you can't use flexbox, if you solve the ordering by changing the order of IDs or animation-delays, right?

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.col {
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
}

#globe-1 > img { animation-delay: 0; }
#globe-2 > img { animation-delay: 3s; }
#globe-3 > img { animation-delay: 6s; }
#globe-4 > img { animation-delay: 9s; }

#globes img {
  width: 40%;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotateZ(0);
  } 
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="globes">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="globe-1" class="col"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/6WD0tuL.png"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="globe-3" class="col"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/6WD0tuL.png"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div id="globe-4" class="col"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/6WD0tuL.png"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="globe-2" class="col"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/6WD0tuL.png"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advance, I will try to do that